# Genetic Algorithm From Desktop Application To MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, genetic-algorithm

I have implemented a GA .NET C# Desktop application with the classes:

- Population
- Individuals
- Genes
- static class to control the DB access
- static fitness function class
- GA class to start the process and draw the loops

I want to migrate these classes to my .NET MVC application but really confused with how are multiple clients going to access these classes without sharing them. I have looked into Singleton classes but did not understand the concept.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You need the *opposite* of singleton classes - different classes instances per user.

Comment: This means I need to covert the static classes to a regular ones => then create a new instance. Can i save this instance at a session ? I mean is the session going to handle the size of the class ?

Comment: You can save an instance in a session, or save the values in a database, or any other kind of persistent or semi-persistent storage you care to mention. N.B. The static DB access class is probably not a big issue, as long as it doesn't store any data in properties or variable, but just passes data from the other classes to the database, and back again. Any static classes which store data will be an issue though. It's not clear what your particular classes actually do.

Comment: Also...how long does it take to draw the loops and finish the algorithm? Is it reasonable to expect it to complete in a few seconds (the amount of time most people are prepared to wait for a web page to reload). If not, then consider if this is the most suitable architecture.

Comment: @ADyson the db class retrieve all related information from the database and stores them in matrixes and vectors. The fitness function class uses them to calculate the fitness value. I have these separate ff and db classes because they represent the Gene information and need to be prepared before introducing them to the population and Individual arrays. For the GA processing time, it takes up to 10 seconds with 50 pop. Size and 1000 max generations.

Comment: stores them in matrixes and vectors...the important point is the status of those variables. If they're stored in static properties of a static class then there's a danger the values could be shared between different user sessions. If they're in non-static properties of an instance of a class then they won't. That's the distinction you need to make here, and then decide whether that's a good thing or not, according to how you want the application to work.

Comment: @ADyson thank you, that was very clear

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is dealing with the same issue. I have implement the solution by:

1. Put all your classes in a separate Folder
2. Then, at the controller with each request: create new instance of a master class that further creates new instances of the others as needed.
3. If you have a class that shall be shared with these instances, save
   its reference in Session["Key"]